# Prevent OptionsMenu from closing when clicking on checkbox

Tags: android, menu

I wanna show checkbox on top of the screen to allow the user to enable screenLock and I want to show that checkbox only if he opens the optionsMenu.
I am able to do this by overridinbg these 2 methods

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}
@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);
}
```

However when I touch the checkbox, in order to check it, the menu closes itself and the checkbox disappears before I can check it.

So my question si simple: How can I prevent the options menu from closing when I touch the checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android stock browser shows a TitleBar you can click while the menu is open. So their solution should fit your problem as well.

The TitleBar is shown using WindowManager:

```
WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

// Add the title bar to the window manager so it can receive touches
// while the menu is up
WindowManager.LayoutParams params
        = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
manager.addView(mFakeTitleBar, params);
```

To remove it (when menu is closed, or user clicks it)

```
manager.removeView(mFakeTitleBar);
```